# Marmalade app: how to determine what memsize needed?

Tags: android, memory-management, marmalade

On my xperia ray app fails on start when memsize > 50mb (can't alloc so mush). But when memsize = 50mb, app can work around 5 mins, and then fails with message from marmalade, that not enough memory. So how can i find out how mush memory my app needs in peak?

In my .icf file:

```
MemSize=200000000

#if resolution < 1080x1920
{ [s3e]DispAreaQ < 2073600 }
MemSize=150000000

#if resolution < 640x854
{ [s3e]DispAreaQ < 546560 }
MemSize=52428800
{}
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to turn on simulator's view matrix option and look under graphics's memory. Check what's the max size it's using. Although simulator's memory usage is different from device's usage, but it'll give you an idea about what memory size is required.

Edit:-
If you need to have different Memsize for debugging you can use MemSizeDebug too, along with MemSize.